# Linking/updating Mac OS X python/python3 in terminal

Tags: python, macos, installation, homebrew, symlink

I have been trying to update python3 (which is currently set to python 3.5.1) on OS X by initially installing Homebrew:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and then installing python:

```
$ brew install python
```

before trying to link my brew installed python as my default I run:

```
$ brew info python3
...
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1 
...
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.1
```

So now I perform the unlinking and linking:

```
$ brew unlink python3 && brew link python3
```

but then I run:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.1
```

Python3 still defaults to the shipped 3.5.1 python. I've looked all over stack overflow can't seem to find a solution or a reason why this might be happening. Any help would be great, thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I guess when I installed python 3.6.1 the command for it was set to python3.6:

```
$ python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.1
```

Comment: What is the output of `which python3`?

Comment: Oh and running `brew doctor` may also help.

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall the current version of Python and either get only the newest via

```
$ brew uninstall your_python_program
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
$ brew install python3
```

or via a very great 
Python package [from here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). Pyenv will allow you to run different Python versions side by side.